# 3NF in Relational Database Design

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-database

Given a schema `R (A,B,C,D)` with functional dependencies `F = {A->B, A->C}` I need to determine if R is in 3NF, but first I need to determine what the candidate keys are so I can determine if B and C are contained in some candidate key.  How would I go about determining the candidate keys?

Answer (score 3):

"How would I go about determining the candidate keys?"

Using normalization theory to determine keys amounts to considering the trivial dependencies that any relation always satisfies.  A->A and D->D in your case.  Use Armstrong's axiom of augmentation, or Darwen's "unification theorem", to determine the FD that has all attributes on the RHS, and a minimal set of attributes on the LHS.

You will then observe that there are certain attributes that depend on a proper subset of the key.

And perhaps label the question as "homework".